# iOS App Crashes while loading image from Assets.xcassets

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

There is an image file named "5.jpg", in the Assets.xcassets named "5".

I wrote code `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"5"];` to create the image but app crashes and outputs `*** Assertion failure in -[_CUIThemePixelRendition _initWithCSIHeader:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreUI/CoreUI-432.4/CoreTheme/ThemeStorage/CUIThemeRendition.m:3797` in the console.

Comment: are you not getting compiler error????  `@` is missing at start of the string image name.

Comment: Must be something in that image that crashes CUIThemeRendition from CoreUI. Change the image and see if it still crashes. If not, you should file a bug report (rdar) on Apple for this.Which iOS version is this happening with ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this problem in the XCode 9 beta, running iOS 10 or below. It seems that Apple has dropped support for JPEG files in XCAssets. You can either use do as @Esha suggested and switch to PNG's or you can not use an XCAsset, put the image in your local directory, and refer to it by its URL.

It's possible that Apple did this intentionally (though if they did, I couldn't find any documentation for it) or that this is an XCode 9 bug. I have reported to apple and you can track the progress of the bug [here.](https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=32712800)

Comment: I think so, I had this problem also in Xcode 9, and I have to use .png instead .jpg, or run it in Xcode 8.

Answer (score 2):

Try puting **.png** images in the asset folder. **jpg** images will make this issue.

Comment: Does this mean that jpg's can't be in an `xcasset` any more?

Answer (score 0):

The line should be

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.jpg"];
```

If the file is in PNG format, it is not necessary to specify the .PNG filename extension. Prior to iOS 4, you must specify the filename extension.

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage)

It is recommended that you use PNG or JPEG files for most images in your app. Image objects are optimized for reading and displaying both formats, and those formats offer better performance than most other image formats. Because the PNG format is lossless, it is especially recommended for the images you use in your app’s interface.